# rename the months of a ts object in r

Tags: r, time-series

Hello I have the following data of a time series object

```
set.seed(2019)
serie <- ts(rpois(72,25), start = c(2012,1), frequency = 12)
serie
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2012  28  22  36  21  26  27  24  26  32  26  29  16
2013  24  28  21  29  31  20  18  25  38  34  23  22
2014  37  25  28  31  21  25  28  26  29  25  23  23
2015  24  23  23  21  16  21  33  23  17  21  30  31
2016  20  23  23  27  23  28  27  23  31  36  25  20
2017  22  24  19  24  26  23  23  25  31  26  23  20
```

I need to change the name of an `ts` object, in r. By default the months are in English but I would like to put them in Spanish. Any idea how to do it. Next I leave the vector with the names I want to put in the ts object.

```
nom <- c("Ene","Feb","Mar","Abr","May","Jun","Jul","Ago","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dic")
```

Comment: Have you tried `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale = "es_ES.UTF-8")`?

Comment: The `Sys.setlocale(...)` command does not work for me. But if I use `Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Colombia.1252;LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Colombia.1252;LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Colombia.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Spanish_Colombia.1252"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print.ts` uses `.preformat.ts` which hard codes `month.abb` which is a vector of abbreviated English month names but we can use `trace` to set `month.abb` to `nom` at the top of that function:

```
trace(.preformat.ts, quote(month.abb <- nom), print = FALSE)
serie
```

giving:

```
     Ene Feb Mar Abr May Jun Jul Ago Sep Oct Nov Dic
2012  28  22  36  21  26  27  24  26  32  26  29  16
2013  24  28  21  29  31  20  18  25  38  34  23  22
2014  37  25  28  31  21  25  28  26  29  25  23  23
2015  24  23  23  21  16  21  33  23  17  21  30  31
2016  20  23  23  27  23  28  27  23  31  36  25  20
2017  22  24  19  24  26  23  23  25  31  26  23  20
```

To turn it off:

```
untrace(.preformat.ts)
```